# How to vectorize the numpy function below?

Tags: numpy

How to vectorize the brute-force function `brute_force` below?

The function below computes a line and plane intersection point:

```
import numpy as np

def ray_plane_intersection_single(x, v, c, p):
    """
    Finds the intersection point of a ray and plane.
     
    Arguments:
        x: np.ndarray of shape (3,) denoting ray origin
        v: np.ndarray of shape (3,) denoting ray direction
         
        #  X - x  // v 
      
        c: np.ndarray of shape (3,) denoting plane point
        p: np.ndarray of shape (3,) denoting plane normal

        #. X - c perpendicular to the normal, <(X - c), p > = 0
     
    Returns:
        np.ndarray of shape (3,) denoting the intersection of ray or plane
    """
    w = c - x
    I = x + (np.dot(w, p) / np.dot(v, p)) * v
    return I
```

If we have N lines and M planes, we can get all the intersection points with the following function `brute_force`:

```
def brute_force(X, V, C, P):
    """
     
    for-loop implementation
     
    Arguments:
        X: np.ndarray (N, 3) denoting ray origin
        V: np.ndarray (N, 3) denoting ray direction
        C: np.ndarray (M, 3) denoting plane point
        P: np.ndarray (M, 3) denoting plane normal
         
    Returns:
        np.ndarray (N, M, 3)

    Assume that X, V, and C, P are consistent.
    """
    N, _ = X.shape
    M, _ = C.shape
    res = np.ones((N, M, 3))

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
            x, v = X[i], V[i]
            c, p = C[j], P[j]
            tmp = ray_plane_intersection_single(x, v, c, p)
            res[i][j] = tmp

    return res
```

Question: how to implement the `brute_force` function in vectorized format in `numpy`?

I tried to implement using vectorization. However, the two implementations have different results.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ray_plane_intersection_single` takrs (3,) arrays.  The `dot` are all scalar values, and the result has the same (3,) shape (from `v`).

The trick with (N,3) and (M,3) arrays is to track those shapes through `w` and the `dots` to a (N,M,3) result.

We may need to use `einsum` or `matmul` instead of `dot`.

---

```
X, V - (N,3)
C, P - (M,3)
res - (N,M,3)
```

in the function

```
w = c-x
W = C[None,:,:] - X[:,None,:] # (N,M,3)

dot(w,p)  # (3,)(3,)=>scalar
d1 = no.einsum('ijk,jk->ij`, W, P)  # (N,M)

dot(v,p)
d2 = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', V, P)   # (N,M)

*v   # (3,)
*V[:,None,:]   # (N,1,3)
```

Together

```
res = d1[:,:,None]/d2[:,:,None] * V[:,None,:]
```

which should be (N,M,3) shape

I probably could use `np.matmul/@` instead of `einsum`, but for now that should work.

In a fuller answer I'd create sample X,V,etc arrays, and prove that my result runs and matches your iteration.  But that's for another time.

---

for 2d arrays, the translation is easy.

```
np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', V, P)
np.einsum('ik,kj->ij', V, P.T)
np.dot(V, P.T)
V @ P.T
```

with a 3d

```
np.einsum('ijk,jk->ij`, W, P)  # (N,M)
no.einsum('ijk,kj->ij`, W, P.T)  # (N,M)
needs some testing to handle j right
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very neat to use the `einsum` np function. Could you elaborate a solution with `np.matmul` (i.e., `@`)? Wanna follow you though process.

Answer (score 0):

@hpaulj thanks a lot. Here is a write-up based on the use `einsum`:

```
def ray_plane_intersection_vectorized(X, V, C, P):
    """
     
    vectorized implementation
     
    Arguments:
        X: np.ndarray (N, 3) denoting ray origin
        V: np.ndarray (N, 3) denoting ray direction
        C: np.ndarray (M, 3) denoting plane point
        P: np.ndarray (M, 3) denoting plane normal
         
    Returns:
        np.ndarray (N, M, 3)

    """
    W = C[None,:,:] - X[:,None,:] # (N,M,3)
    print(f"W shape: {W.shape}")
    d1 = np.einsum('ijk,jk->ij', W, P)  # (N,M)
    print(f"d1 shape: {d1.shape}")
    d2 = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', V, P)   # (N,M)
    print(f"d2 shape: {d2.shape}")
    res = X[:, None, :] + d1[:,:,None]/d2[:,:,None] * V[:,None,:]
    return res
```